# SecurityException(Partial Trust) running Workflow from Windows Forms Application

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to make use of a sequential workflow console application being called from a windows forms app. When the project runs and I click on the button that would create and start the workflow  I get

I get `SecurityException` was unhandled
That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers. I'm calling classes that I call in my **.net2.0** targeted apps just fine. It also works if I drop the same reference into a **.net3.5** targeted windows forms app.

I thought since I have .net 3.5 sp1 I shouldn't have this issue per
[.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Allows managed code to be launched from a network share!](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx)

Why is the workflow security different than anything else I do? I've read a few articles that suggest I add

I'd rather fix the permissions requested by the workflow, where would I do that?

I have signing on for the workflowConsoleApplication and I just added

```
[assembly: System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.RequestMinimum,Name="FullTrust")]
```

to the console application instead I now get this error when I click the button to create and start the workflow:

```
FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'WorkflowConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aac23b652e4eab76' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant minimum permission requests. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131417)
```